# Cannot Execute sudo

Tags: root, sudo, file-ownership

I had accidentally changed ownership of /usr/lib and it's sub folders and files to a user 'A' from it's previous owner 'root'. Now I'm unable to run any command with sudo since root doesn't own usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so file.

Comment: Sounds like you're screwed. Re-root?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea ...

boot from "live cd" or usb stick, mount the disk, change the ownership of  /usr/lib back to what it should be, reboot.